# Recommendation for edition of Mishne Torah with sources

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mishneh-torah

I am learning Rambam's Mishne Torah following the Chabad's [perek-a-day rhythm](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/900030/jewish/Learning-Daily-Rambam-Mishneh-Torah.htm). I find it fascinating. I learn in Hebrew, and use two texts

- the new [Koren's Mishne Torah](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/talmud/mishna/the-koren-mishnah-torah-sefer-hamada-ahava.html) from R Steinsaltz. It is very good because it brings rulings from Shulchan Aruch and other *ahronim* where they differ from the Rambam, and brings nice illustrations and explanations of complicated words
- the [Mifal Mishne Torah](http://www.mishnetorah.co.il/en/) which also brings a nice and simple commentary and is available in 14 volumes so easy to travel with (I do much learning on planes)

Both are highly recommended. Unfortunately, none of them brings the standard commentaries. What I miss most are the sources the Rambam uses for his various rulings. As is well known, the Rambam himself doesn't bring sources but those are incredibly useful to understand the why. For instance when the Rambam [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Marriage.3.19?lang=bi) a father is allowed to but shouldn't marry his underage girl, it would be helpful to know this comes straight from the gemara in [Kiddushin 41a](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.41a.8?lang=bi).

**What are recommendations on editions of the Mishne Torah which bring those sources?** Ideally they should come with a clear and recently printed text, as little Rashi script as possible, abbreviations spelled out and a reasonable price (200-250$ would be an ideal range).

Mosad Harav Kook's [Rambam LeAm](https://www.mosadharavkook.com/shop/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%9D/) might be such an option and your opinion of it would be most welcome.

Comment: Also, for weekdays, if you are a fan of computer learning, I would recommend the [Hebrewbooks Rambam](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam), which has a whole bunch of commentaries, including the standard ones.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://www.nehora.com/mishneh-torah-rambam-15-vol-frankel-edition-medium-size/) or [this](http://www.nehora.com/mishneh-torah-lrambam-medium-7-vol/), if you're willing to lay down the money?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Every so often I find that the hebrewbooks Rambam has the commentaries listed under the wrong halacha.

Comment: @mbloch Btw, I would try searching eBay for Mishne Torah sets and see what you can find... You can save _a lot_ of money that way, especially since you're learning in Hebrew. I'd check there before I paid $700 or something crazy like that. You never know what incredible deals you can find.

Comment: The mifal Mishne Tora is very beautiful but it's without raavad. And to read the raavad is very interesting.

Comment: Online You have the menukad of machine mamre and for comments you have the hebrebooks  digital edition. The last is not well adapted for a phone

Comment: @kouty many thanks. Although I do much learning on planes, since I'm more or less every week in Europe or the US. This is an old question, in the meantime I bought the standard set recommended by msh210 for when I need more than the two mentioned in my question

Comment: Yshach coach. It's a very good learning. To read Magid Mishne is also a great pleasure because he writes very nice and easy as his friend the Ran

Answer (score 5):

I think the Frankel Rambam contains what you are looking for. It has the standard commentaries on the page, such as Maggid Mishnah, Kessef Mishneh, Radvaz, Lechem Mishneh, Migdal Oz, Rabbeinu Manoach, etc.  It also has a section in the back where it lists dozens of other commentaries that speak about each individual halacha.

The text is very clear, and it provides textual variants as well. You can get the entire new set (17 volumes or so) in the small size for $300 - $350.

If that is too expensive, they also have a cheaper set that does not have the additional material in the back, but still has the standard commentaries on the page, in a few volumes.

Additionally, they sell the volumes individually as well, if you don't want to spend so much money at once.

Comment: It is unlikely that someone studying a Perek a day would benefit all that much from the Yalkut Shinui Nuschaos and Mafteach, unless it's a really serious intense Limmud, and they also have an extensive library to look up sources quoted.  It's more useful for research purposes, and people learning it "Beiyun" (and pretty expensive).  Personally speaking, I have the standard set (without extra notes) that Frankel published which works great for me, although I don't do the daily perek.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Most of the sources can be found online (e.g. Hebrewbooks, Otzar Hachochma) and if someone is learning even an unintense learning they might have a specific question. There's a good chance the question is addressed in the Mafteach. It might not justify the additional expense, but it still is useful.

Comment: as usual, you are right on the mark.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex - I believe I will go in this direction

Comment: Thanks @רבותמחשבות indeed I won't need the extra commentaries at least for the next few years. Appreciate the suggestions

Comment: I agree it's the best.

Answer (score 4):

The standard edition, out of copyright and republished by many publishers over the years, sounds like what you want. It's got *Raavad*,  *Kesef Mishne*, *Magid Mishne*, *Lechem Mishne*, *Hagahos Maymaniyos*, and more. In particular, it has *Migdal Oz*, which cites the *Mishne Tora*'s sources. Because this edition has been published by so many, I can't recommend a publisher, but if you ask a Jewish bookseller for the standard old-fashioned *Mishne Tora*, you'll probably get it. It's also (I'm guessing) the cheapest edition with commentaries on the market. A downside is that the print is not as crisp as some newer editions'. And another thing to note (and you may consider it a downside) is that it has the text that everyone had for years, which had been censored to avoid insulting Christianity too much, rather than a more original text that some newer editions have. [Here's a picture of a page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyene.jpg)

Comment: I can recommend the Frankel standard Mishna Torah (http://www.lehmanns.co.uk/rmb-m-prnql-qtn-z-krkim-bli-spr-hmpth.html)

Comment: As a quick followup, just wanted to say I followed your advice and bought one such set. It has all the criteria I spelled out in my question. The Migdal Oz is indeed what I was particularly looking for and it is very helpful. The set I bought looks exactly like the one @רבותמחשבות recommended. Cost was USD 140 for the large edition incl. Sefer Hamitzvot. Thanks to both !

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://chazak.co.il/product/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%9D/) edition is specially made for Chabad program. It contains a lot of bibliographic references. But the font is very small,  it's tiresome to read for hours small letters. It's better than mifal Mishne Tora because of the wide mare mekomot, Raavad is not skipped, for travel it's good. To skip the Raavad is a pity, because notes of Raavad on Rambam are very short and show the reading of this big genius.

There is a pocket version of Eshkol edition, which is also vowelized, and easy to read with a beautiful font, as all Eshkol books. This edition contains Magid Mishne, the most important comment, the "Bartenura of Rambam", the most pleasurable reading which gives us sources of Rambam in a marvelous Hebrew style. This comment upgrades lecture and lector. IMHO this kind of edition is the best.

[This](https://www.mishnetorah.co.il/light-edition/) pocket edition (מפעל משנה תורה) is not beautiful but the text follows manuscripts, but there is missing Raavad notes and Magid Mishne comment. I don't recommend it.

Comment: @mbloch yes. IMHO it's not so good

Comment: מגיד משנה הוא ממש מקדם הרבה מאוד את הלומד מכל הבחינות. ידע, הגיון לימודי, פירוש קל הקטעים מהש''ס