# "Rambam In Context" Sefer

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, commentaries

Is anyone aware of a Sefer which traces the psokim of the Rambam to their source in the Gemoro together with providing the necessary background and other varying halachic opinions? In other words a Sefer which presents the halacha of the Rambam in context with the general Talmudic and Halachic picture of the particular sugya.

Comment: Isn't that what the traditional נושא כלים endeavor to do? Or even more modern commentaries like R. Qafih?

Comment: I'm looking for an all-in-one more modern and easy to read styled book

Comment: @NochieWolf Goodluck. Let us know if you find anything

Comment: related: [Recommendation for edition of Mishne Torah with sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91519/11501)

Answer (score 1):

The classical commentators ([Kesef Mishne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo#Published_works), [Magid Mishne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidal_of_Tolosa#Maggid_Mishneh), [Radbaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra), [Migdal Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shem_Tov_ben_Abraham_ibn_Gaon)) all aim to do what you ask for. The result is complex to read/understand and takes a lot of space (my classical edition takes 8 large volumes and half a standard IKEA bookshelf). But working your way through them with a learned Rav is the best way to understand the incredible work the Rambam did to elucidate a *sugya* and structure the halacha in such a clear way.

Modern editions of the Mishne Torah can also be helpful to understand the context

- R Adin Steinsaltz's [edition of the Rambam](https://korenpub.com/products/rambam-mishneh-torah-sethardcover) brings the source in Shulchan Aruch/other *aharonim* for every halacha and explains all difficult words. It is for now in Hebrew only but there are plans to translate it
- R Eliyahu Touger's translation into English ([available online](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm)) is excellent, the endnotes are extremely valuable and probably the best 'commentary' available in English
- The [Mishne Torah Project's Rambam](https://www.mishnetorah.co.il/desktop-edition_en/) is also excellent, and has a commentary which connects the halachot of the Rambam to other sources in the Rambam himself (e.g., his commentary of the Mishna) with footnotes linking halachot to their talmudic sources. It exists in Hebrew (in book format and digital)

Answer (score 1):

Besides a good answer from mbloch, I would add

1. [Rambam Leam](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=152) a great source which brings the source and context for each halacha in a simple and straightforward language. I don't think as good though with bringing sources from halacha, Rambam Hamevor, the English Rambam from Rabbi Touger, and Steinsaltz's Rambam all do a good job bringing the halacha.

(To get an idea of Rabbi Touger's translation see [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm) where it has his english translation, but only some books have his amazing footnotes.)

2. [Rambam Hamevoar](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HO-RAMBMHA): They are in the middle of printing this series, and have printed about 6 sefarim of the Rambam so far. However, it is a truly amazing piece of work, much more elaborate than Rambam Leam, so it may be a better option, depending on how in depth you want to learn. They bring every Gemara in detail and also have and הלכה למעשה section. I've heard people call this the "Artscroll Rambam" (not that Artscroll made it but that they have done a great job like Artscroll did on their gemara.)

### **Rambam Leam**

[image: Sample Page]

### **Rambam Hamevoar**

[image]